# The procedure entry point _ZNSt3pmr20get_default_resourceEV could not be located in dynamic link library in QT

Tags: c++, windows, dll, deployment, qt6

I am seeing this when running my application:

[image: Snapshot]

I am getting this error even when I have all the required dll in my executable folder. I am using **Windows  11, Qt 6.2 and Mingw 9 64 bit** as a compiler, which I had in my Qt folder itself. Can someone help me with this.

Comment: Errors are better posted as text rather than screenshots. My guess would be that you've built against a different version/build of qt than you're trying to run against

Comment: You either copied the wrong dlls, or forgot some of them. Or possibly the dll was built with a different compiler compared to what you use now.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I have built with mingw 9.00 which i have inside my Qt dir. I even have used dependency walker and found nothing left. I have verified that my dll are from that same folder as from my compiler.

Comment: Can you run [`ntldd -R testQt.exe`](https://github.com/LRN/ntldd) and attach its output?

Comment: Thanks to you both, the problem was that I was having other mingw folder which was standalone and not qt bounded before, so i just put the path of the qt bounded mingw  before that standalone mingw in my env variables and this went right.

Answer (score 0):

As this is (for me) the first google hit for the error message
"_ZNSt3pmr20get_default_resourceEv could not be located", it should have
a proper answer.

### Answer

The OP has explained in comments that the problem is a mismatch between
the DLLs against which Qt was compiled, versus those in the `PATH`.

### Diagnosis

To diagnose this, I used [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) `ldd`.
HolyBlackCat suggests [`ntldd`](https://github.com/LRN/ntldd), which I
didn't try but presumably works as well.

### My particular circumstances

In my specific case, the problem was I had followed the [Qt5 Building
from
Source](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html#building-from-source)
instructions, which meant my `PATH` had, in order:

- [Strawberry Perl](https://strawberryperl.com/)
- [Python](http://www.python.org/download/)
- [Winlibs Mingw](https://winlibs.com/)

It turns out Stawberry Perl also has the Mingw DLLs, but different
versions, causing a conflict when `mingw32-make` tried to run the
`moc.exe` that it had previously built.

However, Perl is still needed during the build, even after running
`configure`, so I couldn't just remove it.  Instead, I put it at the end of
the `PATH`, after the winlibs-mingw directory.  For unrelated reasons
(260 char path limit), I had to restart the Qt build from scratch after
making that change, and it succeeded, so it appears that `perl` still
works (for the Qt build at least), despite now using the wrong DLLs.

(Just for clarity, I still had to make a handful of unrelated changes to the Qt sources and build system to get it all to work.)

This was with Qt-5.15 on Windows 10.